# Changing the attribute "grid-template-areas" through js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the attribute "grid-template-areas" through javascript like this:

```
      document.getElementById("myContainer").style.gridTemplateAreas =
        "'. a .''b c . d f''g h . i j''k . . . .''. l . m .'";
```

doesn't seem to change anything, I inspected in the browser.

Note: the element has a grid-template-areas attribute with another value in its base css before using js

(I don't know why is the question getting marked as a duplicate, this is a different issue, the question I'm getting redirected to doesn't fix my problem at all)